# How to write unit test for button component title using material ui in react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, material-ui

I'm beginner to unit testing, i'm trying to test name for button component using material ui framework.

```
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

test("display button title", () => {
render(<Button/>);
const button = screen.getByRole('button', {name:/create user/i});
expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

Can anyone help me in this. It is showing failed. I don't know where i'm writing wrong.

I'm expecting that the button component name should pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps using the `findBy` query from react testing library can help.  This will allow any rendering state updates, etc., to finish before any assertion is made.

```js
test("display button title", async () => {
 render(<Button/>);
 const button = await screen.findByRole('button', {name:/create user/i});
 expect(button).toBeInTheDocument();
})
```

Amendment with the answer from the comments:

The `screen.getByRole("button", {name: /button name/})` will only find buttons that have a inner HTML value of the name value. If you render the button like below, it should pass with:

```js
render(<Button>create user</Button>)
```

Comment: Hi It is showing error as **unable to find role="button" and name '/create user/'**

Comment: Ignored nodes: comments, script, style

Comment: The button you rendered does not have a name. Does the test pass when you remove {name:/create user/i} and simply get any button?

Comment: yes, when i remove {name:/create user/i} , the test is getting pass

Comment: Ah, yes.  the screen.getByRole("button", {name: /button name/}) will only find buttons that have a inner HTML value of the name value.  If you render the button like below, does it pass with your current test?  

render(<Button>create user</Button>)